# How do I tell PhpStorm to stop open a file with an external editor?

Tags: phpstorm

For some reasons, in my current PHP Project in PhpStorm, when I click on one of my file in my project explorer panel, PhpStorm opens it in an external editor. I have others files with the same extension that opens correctly in PhpStorm.

How can I tell PhpStorm to stop doing that ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`
2. Find `Files Opened in Associated Application` entry in the top list
3. Remove unwanted entry that affects that file from the bottom list (`Registered Patterns`).

[image]

Comment: How did I miss that ! Thank you :)

Comment: Am I missing something, or have they removed this feature?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Still there for me in 2018.2.4

Comment: My hero! Works for me!